# Why listInterator.hasNext() is always returning true?

Tags: java, android

I have a listInterator with only one element in it. I have a function thet need to know id it has next element. But the method hasNext() is always retourning true.

This code is inside a oncliclistener of a button. I just want: when the user click this button, if has next element change some image, if not change to another image.

```
    ListIterator<String> lInterator = datas.listIterator(datas.size() - 1);

     if(lInterator.hasNext()){
            imgDataProxima.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bt_next);
        } else {                    
            imgDataProxima.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btcheckin_next_disabled);
        }

        if(lInterator.hasPrevious()){
            imgDataAnterior.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bt_previous);
        } else {
            imgDataAnterior.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btcheckin_previous_disabled);
        }
```

With my test, I doing with only one element in the array. The hasPreviuos() is woking ok. But hasNext() is retoutning true even with only one element on the array.

Comment: Because you never move the iterator's "position".

Comment: This code is inside a oncliclistener of a button. I just want: when the user click this button, if has next element change some image, if not change to another image.

Comment: Perhaps you want to be checking size of the list?  I think you've misinterpreted the point of iterators, which is about stepping through alist entirely.  To whit, until you call iterator.next(), hasNext() will be true assuming list has at least one element.

Comment: And how to know if the interator a has next element?

Comment: How do I know id my Interator or my Arraylist has a next element?

Comment: It's time for you to read some tutorials and the documentation since you do not understand what you are doing.  Clue.  How to know if an iterator has a next element is in the code you posted! The name even tells you exactly what it does.

Comment: @Simon Im using the mothod hasNext(). It was suposted to retourn false if I have no next element in my interator. The problem is thas is retourning true, even if I have only one element in my interator.

Comment: @Roland: `hasNext()` works fine, if you're getting it from an `ArrayList`.  Your problem is that if you never call `next()`, then `hasNext()` will never change from `true` to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You must implement `lInterator.next()` to forward cursor.

```
if(lInterator.hasNext()){
            imgDataProxima.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bt_next);
            lInterator.next(); // add this row
        } else {                    
            imgDataProxima.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btcheckin_next_disabled);
        }

        if(lInterator.hasPrevious()){
            imgDataAnterior.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bt_previous);
        } else {
            imgDataAnterior.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btcheckin_previous_disabled);
        }
```

Comment: The while will not goona work. I nedd something like If/Else. If has next it will change a image, if has no next it will change to another image.

Comment: I did what you sayed, but it doesn't work. This functions is inside a oncliclistener of a button.

Comment: Sorry but its out of question scope. You asked why `hasNext()` returns true, I gave you solution and where is your problem. I cant review your code

Comment: `it doesn't work`, ah, the most useless statement in software!